# How to place page number in top right corner of title page using scartcl class

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I was able to place page numbers on all other pages using \rhead{\thepage} but the page number on the title page is on the bottom middle. I am using \pagestyle{fancy}. How do I place the page number in the top right?

Comment: The title page by default uses the `plain` pagesstyle. Try adding `\thispagestyle{fancy}` or redefine the plain page style with fancyhdr.

Comment: although this works, I have a running header on the left which I do not want on the title page as well as the line. How would I redefine the plain page style? Thanks

Comment: Do you want a header rule for this title page?

Comment: I think that should work, how would I add the header though without the line showing up

Comment: It is explained in the documentation of fancyhdr (p.13):  `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}` .

Answer (score 1):

With a KOMA-Script class it is recommended to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` for header and footer.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}% short version of \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

This makes page style `plain` the same as `fancy`.
The second (empty) parameter can be used to add additional definitions if you want `plain` to be a little different from `fancy`. So if you don't want the running header on the left, and not the line, use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead[R]{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
```